# Adding references to external dll in asp.net (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll

I have got a .aspx file containing code to look up data from a MySQL server. When I use visual studio (VB) and import the .dll my code works fine. However, I am not sure how to reference the .dll in asp.net (I am using notepad for creating my .aspx file, and hosting using Microsoft IIS 8.0)?

Answer (score 1):

.NET Applications look for DLLs referenced in their code in the 'bin' folder of their project, and the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) where you put system shared DLL's, if not found in the local 'bin'.

If you ensure that you have your DLL in one of the places, you can develop code as you would do in VS after referencing the DLL.

Another option is, adding the `<%@ Assembly Name="" %>` directive in that a particular ASPX, or to the  `<assemblies>` section in web.config if you will need to use it in more than one of your ASPX pages.